# Can I move the password field to the center of the login screen?

Tags: 11.10, login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 ( I reverted back from 12.04 to 11.10 because of stability issues). I would like to know is it possible to change the location of the password field in the login screen ?

Comment: move it where? Can you mock up what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I wish to move the password field from the left side to the center of the screen.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 11):

#### Options for 11.10

The layout of the login screen is controlled by the *greeter* package (plugin) for LightDM; the default with the left-side layout is *unity-greeter*. There's no way to modify *unity-greeter* to do what you want short of changing the source code, but it's easy to get centered layout with these alternative greeters if you don't mind the slightly simple design:

#### 1. Use the *gtk-greeter*:

[image]

- `sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`

  [image: Install via the software center]
- open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and change the `greeter-session=unity-greeter` to:

  ```
  greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
  ```
- save, exit, and either reboot or switch to the console (`Ctrl-Alt-F1`) and run `sudo service lightdm restart`
- 11.10 has a `qt-greeter` (for Kubuntu) and themes for Mythbuntu, but they didn't work for me on regular Ubuntu

---

#### 2. Switch to GDM for a similar layout to (1):

[image]
  [image]

- `sudo apt-get install gdm`

  [image: Install via the software center]
- switch to GDM when you are prompted (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm/158487#158487) for more details or a GUI way to install GDM)

Comment: I had an intention of changing to GDM logi, but I am further more interested in changing the location of the pass word field.

Is it not possible to change the source code of the unity greeter >

Comment: @RoshanGeorge: it's Linux, you can change the source code of almost anything :)  Modifying `unity-greeter` will require decent knowledge of Vala, GTK+ and C programming, as well as of Debian packaging. Note that you will have to re-apply your patches and recompile whenever a new version of `unity-greeter` is released. And no, I'm not going to give you "step by step details" as you requested on how to do all of the above...please feel free to ask additional questions here, or more appropriately, on StackOverflow.

Comment: @RoshanGeorge I do truly hope such a patch comes out.

Comment: In 12.04. there is a nice lightdm greeter. It is `lightdm-kde-greeter`.

Answer (score -1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9068333#post9068333

Best tutorial I can find, but so far it has only been tested for Karmic.

Comment: Though the tutorial at the link you gave says that, it will teach the ways to edit everything from grub menu to the desktop environment, it just teaches the grub tutorial, and also it is updated.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.