# vnc using lightdm and x11vnc disconnects immediately after valid login

Tags: 12.04, server, lightdm, vnc

starting with a precise 64-bit server install, I configured the following;

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm x11vnc
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

in /etc/init/x11vnc.conf, I placed;

```
start on login-session-start
script
/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
end script
```

Using UltraVNC from windows, I connect and enter valid login information, and the window immediately closes.  The vnc log shows;

```
30/04/2013 16:52:01 Got connection from client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:01   other clients:
30/04/2013 16:52:01 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
30/04/2013 16:52:01   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
30/04/2013 16:52:01 incr accepted_client=1 for 10.0.2.2:61281  sock=8
30/04/2013 16:52:01 Client Protocol Version 3.8
30/04/2013 16:52:01 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
30/04/2013 16:52:01 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 1
30/04/2013 16:52:01 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: returning securityResult for client rfb version >= 3.8
30/04/2013 16:52:01 copy_tiles: allocating first_line at size 33
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Pixel format for client 10.0.2.2:
30/04/2013 16:52:02   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
30/04/2013 16:52:02   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
30/04/2013 16:52:02 no translation needed
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000A)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type zlibhex
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Using compression level 6 for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Enabling cursor position updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Using image quality level 6 for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type xorEnable
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type cacheEnable
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8000)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8001)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8002)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8003)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xC0A1E5CE)
30/04/2013 16:52:02 Using ZRLE encoding for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Pixel format for client 10.0.2.2:
30/04/2013 16:52:03   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
30/04/2013 16:52:03   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
30/04/2013 16:52:03 no translation needed
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0x0000000A)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type zlibhex
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Using compression level 6 for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Enabling cursor position updates for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Using image quality level 6 for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type xorEnable
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8000)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8001)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8002)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xFFFF8003)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type Enc(0xC0A1E5CE)
30/04/2013 16:52:03 Switching from ZRLE to hextile Encoding for client 10.0.2.2
30/04/2013 16:52:03 client_set_net: 10.0.2.2  0.0015
caught XIO error:
30/04/2013 16:52:07 deleted 32 tile_row polling images.
tail: x11vnc.log: file truncated
30/04/2013 16:52:08 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
30/04/2013 16:52:08 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: For people that come here for fix this, currently Remmina has a bug to cause this. https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/1786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turns out to be relatively simple, I hadn't installed an underlying desktop provider.  Also, my appliance has no video card and no video driver, so, no frame buffer in which to render.

The solution that worked for me was found in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/524811/how-can-i-run-lightdm-on-xvfb-on-a-raspberrypi).

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem by switching desktop manager from `lightdm` to `gdm`.

here is a detailed instruction: [How do I switch from LightDM to GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred here, the solution was aplying [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/716168) and configure color depth properly (32 bits in my case). The latter was the problem with remmina.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem (basically same exact log output) and in my case it was because a file in my home folder `.ICEauthority` became somehow owned by root. Probably because I ran something with sudo during debugging. Chown back to my user fixed it

Some useful logging might be in `/var/log/lightdm/`