# gdm subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: gdm

```
root@saimon-System-Product-Name:~# dpkg --install /home/saimon/Downloads/gdm-2.20_2.20.10-0ubuntu3_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 165751 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gdm-2.20_2.20.10-0ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gdm-2.20 (2.20.10-0ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/saimon/Downloads/gdm-2.20_2.20.10-0ubuntu3_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/astronaut.jpg', which is also in package gnome-control-center-shared-data 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/saimon/Downloads/gdm-2.20_2.20.10-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Im really new on linux im trying to setup multiseat on my PC and stack here can somebody help me 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard

Comment: i find the solution 
here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from OPs comments

> i find the solution here [askubuntu.com/questions/152256/…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm) 
>   `sudo apt-get install gdm`