# Notebook wakes up from Standby

Tags: 14.04, power-management, hibernate, wakeup, standby

I have an Acer Aspire V5 Notebook with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a SSD an Windows 8.1 on a HDD.

I experience that my Notebook wakes up from standby randomly after a certain time (can be a few seconds, minutes or some 10 hours). This only happens in Ubuntu, Windows 8.1 is not affected. I cannot find a pattern under which situations the hibernation is interrupted. It happens if the hibernate/standby is induced by closing the lid or using the software button for standby.

Another issue which might be related is that i cannot select "hibernate" as the low battery action in the power section. It is greyed out. I am not sure if this has anything to do with my problem, I just wanted to mention it in case there is a connection.

This behaviour is potentially dangerous for the hardware: when I carry my notebook in a bag and it turns itself on, it can cause heat accumulation in the bag and the device might get damaged from overheating.

As the wake up does not always appear (in 80% percent of all standby phases, I would guess) the debugging is non trivial.

Output of uname -a: `Linux LappII 3.16.0-43-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 10:21:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

EDIT: This behaviour might be related to this bug: [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1161962)

I changed all entries in /etc/acpi/wakeup to *disabled* but this had no effect.

Comment: Try to update the kernel, this worked to me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: @MarcosRocha What do you mean with "this worked to me"? Did you experience the same problem and updating to a mainline kernel helped? Which specific kernel did you choose? And considering this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/162617/317977, installing a mainline kernel can cause lots of trouble. So can you expand your comment a bit, please?

Comment: I had the same problem, with other hardware (Asus motherboard), but when I upgraded the kernel to 3.18 this problem over. I can suspend or hibernate the PC and this not turn on until a mouse click or press any key.

Comment: Have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm ? Seems a spurious wakeup event around...

Comment: Are you saying that lightdm causes the wake ups and I should switch to gdm?

Answer (score 0):

I would try suspending (standby) with this command:

`dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend`

Change Suspend to Hibernate if you want to hibernate instead

I would probably create an alias in ~/.bashrc such as `alias standby="dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend"`

Note that the mentioned commands don't require superuser privileges.

Comment: Well, this wouldn't fix the problem if i close the lid of my notebook, right?