# Can't type password or click anything on wake

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, suspend, lock-screen

I'm having a little issue when I wake my desktop up. After I wake it up by moving the mouse, I'm unable to type in my password to unlock. I can move the mouse cursor around but it also won't let me click anything. I have to physically restart the computer every time.

I've tried a few things that others suggested on similar questions but nothing has worked. Here's a list of what I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`
- switching kernels (4.7.1, 4.7, 4.4.0-34.53)
- using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> which does nothing

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04. Graphics card is Radeon R9 270X using the open source AMDGPU driver. Let me know any other info needed.

Update 08/24/16 - I have a triple monitor setup. For some reason only 2 of the 3 monitors wake up upon moving my mouse. I'd almost call it a freezing issue but I can still move the mouse cursor around. I disabled f.lux thinking that could be an issue. That didn't help. I also uninstalled the emojione indicator since I had installed it just prior to the issues. After that it would sporadically let me input my password and log back in but not often at all.

Comment: While it won't resolve the root cause of your issue, have you tried installing a different display manager? Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm) post out for more information.

Comment: It could be interesting to see if there's anything in the syslog when the 'freeze' happens. Or perhaps in one of the logs in /var/log/lightdm, I wouldn't know which one though.

Comment: Have you tried the AMDGPU-PRO driver? It's compatible with your card. You'll have to download it from AMD.

Comment: @Tobias - I'm not even sure what to look for.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - I haven't. From what I can tell it's not yet compatible with my card but is compatible with the M270X.

Comment: Here's an excellent list of SysRq commands you should be able to send regardless of the state of X: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-unresponsive-or-frozen-computers-with-keyboard-shortcuts/. If these do not work, it is most likely a hardware issue, either in the HDD or the Motherboard. That being said, I've never seen a system that doesn't respond to Ctrl+Alt+F*.

Comment: @Tobias Absolutely. Here is syslog [link](http://pastebin.com/agLbxbWT). The lightdm log looks very short. Almost like it started generating upon restart this morning.

Comment: @TMartin Is this from when the system 'froze'? I'm seeing a lot of gnome-session stuff being logged I haven't seen before, but it looks as if the system is being actively used right up until the end of the log.