# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot/login time - xorg crashing on startup

Tags: boot, xorg, multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, 11.7GB ram, Intel i7-3770 processor, 2TB rotating disk. I've got 3 monitors and I use 6 virtual work spaces and I'm using unity.

On a reboot, the desktop loads very slowly after I log in and the visual layout of panels gets "stuck" for a while with fragmented panels. The mouse is trapped inside one monitor and unity is partially responsive with a lot of lag. After about 20-30 seconds it fixes itself and my desktop becomes normal. Could this slowness be related to having a rotating disk?

I get the usual "System Program Problem Detected" pop up after my first login. I cleaned out my `/var/crash/` dir and rebooted and I still get the error so I don't think it's stale crash logs.

There is one crash file (which I've elided):

`_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash`:

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Tue May 16 09:11:00 2017
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
ExecutableTimestamp: 1485390561
ProcCmdline: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
ProcCwd: /
ProcEnviron: 
ProcMaps:
 ...
ProcStatus:
 Name:  Xorg
 Umask: 0022
 State: S (sleeping)
 ...
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   4088352
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    204945
Signal: 6
Uname: Linux 4.8.0-49-generic x86_64
UserGroups: 
CoreDump: base64
 ...
```

I've done a couple of reboots clearing the crash logs each time and consistently get the same ProcCmdline:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

Here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head`:

```
8.827s docker.service
7.404s dev-sda2.device
3.171s apparmor.service
2.087s ModemManager.service
1.893s dev-loop2.device
1.864s accounts-daemon.service
1.710s thermald.service
1.667s NetworkManager.service
1.569s plymouth-start.service
1.408s systemd-timesyncd.service
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a solid state disk fixed this. Reduced boot time by 20+ seconds!

Like Josh A. pointed out, it wasn't related to xorg crashing.

Comment: I have the exact same issue in 16.04. Did you do a reinstall when you switched to a SSD?

Comment: @derelict Yeah I did reinstall. The OS itself was on the rotating disk which was the issue. Good luck!

Comment: In that case it seems more likely that it was a software problem that was solved by the reinstall, but well, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

More of a comment, but I lack the reputation...
The crash log you've provided points to LightDM crashing. LightDM, among other things, is responsible for showing the greeter/login screen. Since your problem occurs *after* you login, the crash log is likely unrelated. Nevertheless, you could try installing a different display manager. [Here are instructions on how to switch from LightDM to GDM.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm) Probably not your root cause, but always worth a shot when LightDM is giving you lemons.

Comment: Thanks @Josh A. I tried to follow the instructions to switch to gdm but it shut down my computer and it took a couple of tries to restart it and get back in, so I'm a bit hesitant to mess further with this. Also the instructions seem a little out of date. After a restart I got another crash log with the same lightdm ProcCmdLine so I guess I failed to switch over. Given that it's probably unrelated to the slowness I'll leave it alone :)