# Ubuntu 18.04 login screen still showing ubuntu 16.04 lts style login

Tags: 18.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 from ubuntu 16.04. But after restarting the login screen was same as 16.04 and still 16.04 lts was written at the bottom. And when I try to login I can't as it shows a black screen momentarily but again redirects to login page. Tell me what to do?

Comment: press alt + ctrl + f1 and login as root than run this command: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: It is a matter of switching to the gdm display manager (see my answer). An upgrade upgrades installed software, so if you were using lightdm in 16.04, the upgrade will keep you on lightdm (and likely also on the Unity desktop if you were using that).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses lightdm as login manager. This is (obviously) preserved if you upgrade to 18.04. If you prefer to use gdm, you will need to switch from lightdm to gdm. How you can do that is explained [elsewhere on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm). [How do I switch from LightDM to GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm)

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall lightdm (by removing and installing again) and when it asks what manager to use, don't select lightdm and instead, you need to select gdm3 and then uninstall lightdm.