# Ugly Lock-Screen in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, lock-screen

I am trying to change the lock-screen type but couldn't. It is looking like of 90s.

I saw my friends lock-screen but in that the time is in the middle of the screen and when trying to login it is looking stylish.

look at this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some how it seems from your Image that you are using lightDM as Display Manager..

the one with time you saw in other computers is GDM.. you yourself changed the default DM..

Go back to GDM to have the default Display Manager that comes with Ubuntu 18.10

follow this link for "how to change the DM from LightDM to GDM" [How do I switch from LightDM to GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/152256/739431)