# Is LightDM necessary after installing GDM3

Tags: lightdm, gdm

Do I need to keep LightDM after installing GDM3. If not then will it effect any other programmes on removing. Please do not hesitate to ask any info or data needed regarding this problem.

**N.B.: I wanna remove because it's slowing my boot time.**

Specifications:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Memory: 7.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G3250 @ 3.20GHz × 2
Graphics: AMD® Cedar
GNOME: 3.28.2
OS type: 64-bit
```

Comment: Did you make GDM the default? If you did, LightDM won't even be running, so it can't be slowing your boot. If you didn't, you should make it the default and see if things work fine for you.

Comment: @muru yes gdm3 (its showing gdm3 not gdm not shure why) is default but still in boot sequence this error is showing `audit: type=1400 audit(1586965081.908:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=378 comm="apparmor_parser"`

Comment: Which is just AppArmor loading a profile. It loads lots of profiles.

Comment: @muru So should I ignore it and rest or remove lightdm?

Comment: You can remove it; it's not going to make any difference to your boot time.

Comment: @muru as you are saying it's not hamper any time boot load time can I get your suggestion of whether I should keep it or remove it.

Comment: You can keep both. But you have to configure which one you want to use. This post has the info to help you - https://askubuntu.com/a/158487/150363