# ubuntu 20.04 [change in login screen after installing lxqt]

Tags: gnome, login, 20.04, screen, lxqt

so I installed lxqt for trying it out and after removing everything back to normal, the only thing that remains is changing this login screen back to default one.

[image]

also when I try to power off, I get the message "other users are logged in and it shows my username.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/906691/631600

Comment: I don't recognize your screen, but suspect pLumo & Mark Kirby are correct and it's https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sddm-theme-debian-elarun you are looking at (I'm used to Lubuntu's which looks different). It'll depend on how exactly how you installed LXQt (which obviously wasn't via `lubuntu-desktop` and you didn't specify), but maybe https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lxqt which does include said package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed LxQt it changed the display manager from the default GDM to SDDM, this was likely not uninstalled with the desktop.

Log back in to your desktop and open a terminal, type

```
sudo service sddm stop
```

to stop the current display manager, then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
sudo service gdm3 start
```

to set the new (default) one.

Now you will have to reboot for this to take effect.

Comment: thx, it helped me.