# Center the login screen on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen, 23.10

Since I got my Ubuntu 23.10 installed the login screen text box stays on the left, whereas I believe it should be in the center of the screen. Here is a picture of my login screen:

[image: login screen showing text box on the left side]

I don't know if this is normal but any help with this would be amazing.

Comment: Are you sure that's the default gdm3, not the old lightdm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not see that outdated `lightdm` login screen. Let's make sure you're using the new `gdm3` login manager, which is also needed for your lock screen to work:

1. Install the correct login screen and desktop:

   ```
   sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
   ```
2. Remove all other providers of `x-display-manager`:

   ```
   sudo apt purge xdm wdm slim sddm nodm lxdm lightdm greetd
   ```
3. When `lightdm` is removed, you might see a dialog in the terminal asking you to select the display manager. Select `gdm3`.
4. Reboot.

I only remember seeing lightdm 10 years ago. See [@BeastOfCaerbannog's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1502908/1004020) for how this could have happened to you.

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely using LightDM (`lightdm` package) as your login manager (as [@Daniel T said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502854/center-the-login-tab-ubuntu-23-10#comment2635339_1502854)) instead of the default GDM (`gdm3` package). I suppose that you ended up with LightDM either because you didn't do a clean install, rather you upgraded from another installation where you had `lightdm` installed, or because you followed some guide to configure your system and you installed `lightdm` without noticing.

To remove `lightdm` and replace it with `gdm3` run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
systemctl stop lightdm
sudo apt remove lightdm
systemctl start gdm3
```

- Reference: [@Sophia Marie's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133791/618353) in [How do I switch from LightDM to GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/152256/618353)